# Calcular Índice de Massa corporal em C

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um simples programa em C para calcular o índice de massa corporal. Porém, está retornando um valor diferente(errado) que uma calculadora comum.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float height, weight, imc;

    printf("Hello World!\nWhat's your height?");
    scanf("%f", &height);

    printf("What's your weight?");
    scanf("%f", &weight);

    imc = height / (weight * height);
    printf("%f", imc);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Expressão:
Altura / peso²

Comment: Quais os valores que estao retornando? Dê um exemplo, por gentileza

Comment: Se é  peso², tens de por `imc = height / (weight * weight );`

Comment: O resultado é relativo, pois depende da altura e peso inseridos. Mas se eu colocasse 1.80 e 80 o resultado correto seria 24,69 porém retorna 0.555556

Comment: [IMC é peso (massa) dividido pela altura ao quadrado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Dndice_de_massa_corporal), e não o contrário. E no seu código, você está dividindo altura por peso vezes altura, o que dá simplesmente o inverso do peso...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    int main() {
    float height, weight, imc;

    printf("Hello World!\nWhat's your height?");
    scanf("%f", &height);

    printf("What's your weight?");
    scanf("%f", &weight);

    imc = weight / (height * height);
    printf("%f", imc);

    getch();
    return 0;


}
```

Se você quer colocar a função getch(); tem de incluir a biblioteca `#include <conio.h>`
`getch();` não faz parte da linguagem padrão

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo `imc = height / (weight * height);` ou seja, altura / (peso * altura). Deveria ser `imc = height / (weight * weight);`

Comment: A formula está errada

Comment: Na minha opinião, essa resposta não merece votos negativos, porque respondeu satisfatoriamente segundo a especificação. O fato da especificação estar errada não lhe tira o mérito, pois não é obrigação de ninguém [que não seja da área da saúde] saber o que é um IMC nem como calculá-lo.

Comment: Mas a pergunta era concretamente porque é que o resultado estava errado, e a resposta prende-se na formula estar incorrecta

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes O corpo da pergunta (exceto pelos comentários) só diz que o resultado está diferente do calculado por uma calculadora comum, e não dá exemplos, só a fórmula. O código dessa resposta está consistente com a fórmula, de modo que o resultado não estaria "errado". De todo modo, eu concordo com você que a resposta não está tecnicamente correta (por isso não dei +1) ainda que não a considere de todo errada (por isso não dei -1).